# Uses of data types in linked lists

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, linked-list

While creating a linked list, a data type is supposed to be defined beforehand. Here's a pseudocode for creating a new linked list:

```
Type ListNode
    Declare Pointer as integer
    Declare data as string
EndType

Declare Namelist[1-50] of Listnode
For Index=1 to 49
    Namelist[Index].pointer=Index + 1
Endfor
Namelist[50].pointer=0
```

What confuses me is the similarity between `newly defined data types` and multidimensional arrays where multiple data elements could be stored.

How do `newly defined data types` allow the storage of multiple different data elements within a single array element?

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I want to define few things. I am considering C programming language here.

**Array**: An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type.

**Basic data-type**: A basic type is a data type provided by a programming language as a basic building block.

**Struct**: A struct in the C programming language (and many derivatives) is a complex data type declaration that defines a physically grouped list of variables to be placed under one name in a block of memory, allowing the different variables to be accessed via a single pointer, or the struct declared name which returns the same address.

> How do newly defined data types allow the storage of multiple different data elements within a single array element?

As mentioned above, array contains object of a single type. If you have defined a struct (in C) or a class (in Java), you can store objects of type defined by you in an array and each array element will be a compound element.

**Example**

```
typedef struct student {
     int id;
     char name[30];
} Student;
```

This defines a type called `struct student` and we have set a name (`Student`) for the type using `typedef`. **Note that**, `typedef` is just a way to alias a type with a specific name.

Now, we can declare variables or array of variables of type `Student`:

```
Student record;
Student records[10];
```

We can declare the above in the following way as well.

```
struct student record;
struct student records[10];
```

Here, `record` is a single variable and `records` is an array which contains 10 variables of type `struct student`.

Now each element of array `records` has two data elements, `id` (type int) and `name` (type char array). This is how you can store different data elements in a single element of an array.

Note that if you declare an array of primitive data types, say `integer` or `double`, you will only be able to store elements of a that specific type, not elements with different data types in the array.

**Multidimensional array**

```
int var[2][3];
```

Here, `var` is a multidimensional (2d) array which can hold 6 (2 x 3) integer values. **Note that**, even though `var` is a 2d array, it can only contain elements of type `int`, not others.

Your understanding about multidimensional arrays is incorrect. As you said, in multidimensional array, multiple data elements could be stored. **It is correct but all the data elements will be of same type.** So, there is no similarity between multidimensional array and our defined data types (say struct in C).